# How to extract substring with Regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string:

```
x <- "\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\tGEO Publications\n\t\t\t\t\tHandout\n\t\t\t\t\t\tNAR 2013 (latest)\n\t\t\t\t\t\tNAR 2002 (original)\n\t\t\t\t\t\tAll publications\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tFAQ\n\t\t\t\tMIAME\n\t\t\t\tEmail GEO\n\t\t\t\n                    \n                \n                    \n                    \n                \n                    \n                           NCBI > GEO > Accession Display\nNot logged in | Login\n\n                    \n                \n                    \n                    \n                \n                    \n                        \n                                    \n\n \n \n\nGEO help: Mouse over screen elements for information.\n\nScope: SelfPlatformSamplesSeriesFamily\n  Format: HTMLSOFTMINiML\n  Amount: BriefQuick\n GEO accession:   \n\n\n\n    Sample GSM935277\n\nQuery DataSets for GSM935277\nStatus\nPublic on May 22, 2012\nTitle\nStanford_ChipSeq_GM12878_TBP_IgG-mus\nSample type\nSRA\n \n\nSource name\nGM12878\nOrganism\nHomo sapiens\nCharacteristics\nlab: Stanfordlab description: Snyder - Stanford Universitydatatype: ChipSeqdatatype description: Chromatin IP Sequencingcell: GM12878cell organism: humancell description: B-lymphocyte, lymphoblastoid, International HapMap Project - CEPH/Utah - European Caucasion, Epstein-Barr Viruscell karyotype: normalcell lineage: mesodermcell sex: Ftreatment: Nonetreatment description: No special treatment or protocol appliesantibody: TBPantibody antibodydescription: Mouse monoclonal. Immunogen is synthetic peptide conjugated to KLH derived from within residues 1 - 100 of HumanTATA binding protein TBP. Antibody Target: TBPantibody targetdescription: General transcription factor that functions at the core of the DNA-binding multiprotein factor TFIID. Binding of TFIID to the TATA box is the initial transcriptional step of the pre-initiation complex (PIC), playing a role in the activation of eukaryotic genes transcribed by RNA polymerase II."
```

What I want to do is to detect pattern in this form:

```
Antibody Target: TBPantibody
```

And return the substring result `TBPantibody`.

I tried this regex but it doesn't work

```
sub("Antibody Target: ([A-Zaz]+)\\W+", "\\1", x)
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: You are aware that deleting a question (a different one) silently, when the answer has been given could cause bad feelings in people who spent their time on helping you, aren't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
sub(".*Antibody Target: ([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "TBPantibody"
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following once.

```
sub("(.*Antibody Target: )([^ ]*)",\\2,variable)
```

Explanation: As per OP's sample value is stored in variable named `variable` here. Using `sub` to substitute function of Base R here.

***`sub`'s syntax:***

> sub(/regex_to_match/,"get_value_either_from_memory_of_matched_regex OR
>   place new variable/value to be there in matched
>   part",variable_name_which needs to be worked on)

`"(.*Antibody Target: )([^ ]*)"`: First mentioning regex where it matches from starting of variable's value till string `Antibody Target:` and keeping it in memory of R program(`(....)` denotes that a match of mentioned regex is kept there. In second `(..)` mentioning regex to keep everything till first space occurence is there. Then `\\2` means replacing whole variable value with 2nd part in memory(which should be matched string after Antibody..).